# Process JSON Responses, Editing and Sending

Tags: python, json

I am working with an API.  I get a response from the API which looks like this:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, auth=auth)

client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token, auto_refresh_url=token_url,token_updater=token_saver)

token_saver = []

device_policy = client.get('{URL}/v1?ids='+ids)
```

I get this response

```
[{'id': '',
  'name': 'A Name',
  'description': '',
  'platform_name': 'Windows',
  'groups': [],
  'enabled': True,
  'created_by': 'An Email',
  'created_timestamp': '2019-03-28T12:51:30.989736386Z',
  'modified_by': 'An Email ,
  'modified_timestamp': '2019-11-19T21:14:53.0189419Z',
  'settings': {'enforcement_mode': 'MONITOR_ENFORCE',
   'end_user_notification': 'SILENT',
   'classes': [{'id': 'ANY', 'action': 'FULL_ACCESS', 'exceptions': []},
    {'id': 'IMAGING', 'action': 'FULL_ACCESS', 'exceptions': []},
    {'id': 'MASS_STORAGE', 'action': 'BLOCK_ALL', 'exceptions': []},
    {'id': 'MOBILE', 'action': 'BLOCK_ALL', 'exceptions': []},
    {'id': 'PRINTER', 'action': 'FULL_ACCESS', 'exceptions': []},
    {'id': 'WIRELESS', 'action': 'BLOCK_ALL', 'exceptions': []}]}}]
```

In each class there is list for hold exceptions.  The API accepts a patch (not really a patch) that if this data is resubmitted with the exception field holding the contents of this function then an exception is accepted.

`

```
file_info =     {
                            "class": "ANY",
                            "vendor_name": "",
                            "product_name": "",
                            "serial_number": serial_number,
                            "combined_id": "",
                            "action": "FULL_ACCESS",
                            "match_method": "VID_PID_SERIAL"
                        }
```

`

The challenge I have is accepting the first document and then adding the exception material to create a this patch request. I can "walk" the document but cannot work how to create a new body text to send. I think I want to do something like this but not using append as this throws an error.

`new_walk_json = walk_json.append(['classes'][0]['exceptions']['Test'])`

Answer (score 1):

Realised .update function can used.